# Is $\mathbb{R}$ a subset of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I'm curious as why $\mathbb{R} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$, since $\mathbb{R}^{2} = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} = \left \{ (a,b) \mid a\in \mathbb{R}, b\in \mathbb{R} \right \}$. Do we think of $\mathbb{R}$ as being $\mathbb{R} \times 0$ in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically no, for the reason you stated. However there IS a canonical bijection between $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{R}\times \{0\}$.

Comment: canonical homeomorphism I'd say

Comment: @ForeverMozart Well that too. But OP didn't ask about the extra structure. There is a diffeomorphism, isomorphism, homeomorphism, etc. You are correct though.

Comment: oh right. I thought I read subspace .

Comment: Alright, I have a follow up question then. In an algebraic topology book I'm working out of it says the topological pair $(X, A)$ consists of a topological space  $X$ and a subspace $A$. In an exercise at the end of the section it has a problem regarding the pair $(CX,X)$, where $CX$ is the cone over $X$. So why is $X$ a subset of $CX$?

Comment: @user1058860 That appears to be a little bit of sloppiness, although I'm not quite sure. That might be a question to ask as another question. :)